# Checking if Apache is in Debug mode

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there anyway I can check inside .htaccess if apache is running in debug mode (one worker, "apache2ctl -X") ?

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish with this?  Apache's conditional logic isn't exactly robust.

Comment: Well, I am running Apache with mod_wsgi and django. In order to debug the django application, I must run Apache as a single worker (and attach the process to the terminal) and mod_wsgi in embedded mode. When I am not debugging, I am running Apache in normal mode and mod_wsgi in daemon mode. That's why I need to determine what's the status of Apache so I can config mod_wsgi in .htaccess accordingly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `mod_wsgi`, but why did you need to check it from `.htaccess`? If Apache is already starting in debug mode, and you changes mod_wsgi config, do you need to reload?